# Write algorithm to identify symptom pairs

Tags: r

Since I'm a new R user, I am struggling with writing a loop or similar to solve the following problem.

So the problem:
I have a list of 200 patients and 30 symptoms with the info symptom present yes (1) or no (0). I want to create a matrix similar to a correlation matrix, that for every pair of symptoms tells me the percentage of both symptoms being present in the same individuals.

So:

```
ID /sym 1 / sym 2 / sym 3 /....
Pat 1 / 1 / 1 / 0 / ...    
Pat 2 / 1 / 1 / 1 /
Pat 3 / 1 / 1 / 0 / 
...
```

I would then like to use a matrix that looks like a standard correlation matrix, but for every symptom pair show the percentage of both present, since I think that correlating these categorical values does not make any sense.

So far I have started writing for every combination a new variable that tells me if both are present or not, and then used that to calculate the percentage and fill that in my matrix.

Unfortunately that takes FOREVER to write given the amount of combinations possible, but I cant figure out how to iterate through it. Maybe you can help? Its probably very easy and im just not enough of a programmer to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let x be the 200 by 30 data array.  By the rules of matrix multiplication, x' * x is a 30 by 30 array whose (i,j) entry counts the number of places where columns i and j equal 1.  Dividing those counts by 200 gives the proportion and multiplying that by 100 converts it to the desired percentage.

Here is the one-line implementation along with code to test and illustrate it.  On a problem 10,000 times larger than yours (20,000 patients and 3000 symptoms) it takes about 10 seconds to execute on this machine.  Since it scales almost linearly with size, the computation for your problem should require about one millisecond.

```
#
# For columns i and j, f(x)[i,j] is the percentage of rows in which
# both columns of `x` are TRUE (optionally: nonzero).
#
f <- function(x) (t(x) %*% x) * (100 / dim(x)[1])
#
# Slow version to demonstrate `f` is correct.
#
f.direct <- function(x) {
  m <- dim(x)[1]
  n <- dim(x)[2]
  #
  # Test all elements of `x` to create a logical array.
  #
  x.indicator <- x != 0
  #
  # Initialize the result.
  #
  y <- matrix(NA_real_, n, n)
  #
  # Loop over pairs of columns.
  #
  for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      # Compare column `i` to column `j` by averaging the times their
      # indicators are equal.  Multiply by 100 to give a percentage.
      y[i,j] <- 100 * mean(x.indicator[,i] & x.indicator[,j])
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# Create some data and test `f` on them.
#
m <- 200  # Number of rows
n <- 30   # Number of columns
p <- 0.1  # Expected proportion of 1's
x <- matrix(runif(m*n) < p, m, n)

system.time(y <- f(x))                # Almost instantaneous
system.time(y.direct <- f.direct(x))  # A thousand times slower (but not bad)
#
# Display the results.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image(y, main="Matrix Result")
image(y.direct, main="Direct Result")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Compare them and report the outcome.
#
if(all.equal(y, y.direct)) cat("Results are equal.") else cat("There's a difference!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I will spend the weekend trying to understand this!

Comment: Ok, so I have been trying to reproduce your code:  The code itself works, but the resulting matrix should have a diagonal with only 1, as that's comparing the symptoms with each other so they are 100% present. When running your code I get a diagonal which is higher than the rest, but not 100% when looking at the actual y matrix. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's not 100%, nor should it be: you requested "for every pair of symptoms tells me the percentage of both symptoms being present in the same individuals."  When a symptom is paired with itself, you should therefore obtain the proportion of all individuals having that symptom.  If this isn't what you want, then please clarify your request by editing the post.  Consider providing a simple example.  (I'm sure this technique is easily modified to produce whatever variation of this number you might be looking for.)

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. No I can work with this! Im just trying to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately my upvote only gets recorded, not shown

Comment: I believe it takes effect once you have a minimum reputation, somewhere around 15 points.  I had forgotten to upvote your question (if a question's good enough to answer, it's good enough to vote for!), so now there's your first 5 points.